# Create oblique projection?

Tags: coordinate-system

bit of an odd one which isn't necessarily package-specific.

I'm trying to make a tshirt with a map section centred on the plane between San Francisco, USA, to Galway, Ireland. The Great Circle line between them goes over northern Canada and the Hudson Bay. What I'd like is to make a oblique projection of the earth with that plane as the 'equatorial line'. If that's possible, I'd prefer the projection to be Miller 1 rather than Mercator, but I'm not too fussy since the greatest distortions will be farthest away from the area of interest. This will result in a tshirt whereby one place is on the front, one on the back, joined across the side of the tshirt, which may be hard to print.
In the course of my investigations I've recently seen the Werner (2nd Stabius) map (http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Normal/ProjPCon/) which would be perfect as a front or back only (easier for standard tshirt printing) AND is a lovely heart (aww) BUT is less likely to be supported by map projection programmes I assume. Nonetheless if I could make one of those where I could set my own angle and pole, that would be dandy.

I've looked into a variety of tools but come up short so far. I'm not aware that QGis can set a projection which doesn't use the standard equator/poles & angle?

Thanks in advance for any clever ideas!
p.s. this is the centring i'm talking about, but obviously suffers huge distortion at the edges, where the points of interest are: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FIwm.jpg
If anything, I might even be interested in a projection which minimised the centre of focus to the benefit of the edge regions...

Comment: You can follow my answer here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193688/produce-oblique-mercator-map